# I am confused on how I would push to an array using useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

When I used the standard setDate(prev => ({...prev, data}) to try and push to an array I just overwrite to the previous array, how would I push to an array using useState?

my code:

```
const LightMode = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res=>{
            res.data.forEach(country =>{
                //console.log(country)
                setData((prev) => ([{...prev,
                    name: country.name.common,
                    population: country.population,
                    region: country.region,
                    capital: country.capital,
                    image: country.coatOfArms.png}]))
            })
        })
    }, [])

    console.log(data)

    return(
        <div>
            <NavigationBar />
            <div className='temp'>
                <Card className='country-cards'>
                    <Card.Img variant='top' src={data?[0].image: null}/>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title></Card.Title>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LightMode;
```

but all this does is overwrite to the new item in the array and I want to push or append an new item to the array, I want to know how I can accomplish this? Any help is wanted.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move ...prev a bit "up"

```
setData((prev) => [
  ...prev,
  {
    name: country.name.common,
    population: country.population,
    region: country.region,
    capital: country.capital,
    image: country.coatOfArms.png
  }
]);
```

Also, you can prepare data to insert and get rid of .forEach

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all").then((res) => {
    const toInsert = res.data.map((x) => ({
      name: x.name.common,
      population: x.population,
      region: x.region,
      capital: x.capital,
      image: x.coatOfArms.png
    }));

    setData((prev) => [...prev, ...toInsert]);
  });
}, []);
```